# Formtastic's default css is broken in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, formtastic

Take a look at the following url in chrome & firefox: http://dota2.herokuapp.com/accounts/login

Could someone show me how to get the forms displaying the same in both firefox and chrome?
I find it hard to believe that this bug is in the default formtastic installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Float:left` from your `H2` or you can give `clear:both` to your `form#user_new`

Comment: Wow nice catch! How did you figure that out that quickly?